# Run psexec.exe by jenkins hosted in Docker container, error "handle is invalid"

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers, psexec

I got following error when Jenkins hosted in docker Windows container executing a psexec command. How to resolve this? thanks.

Jenkins output:

```
C:\jenkins\workspace\HAT-Dev>c:\windows\temp\PSexec \\\\15.15.183.123 -u Work2019 -p password  -s -i 0 -d -e -accepteula EXPLORER "http://www.google.com" 

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

The handle is invalid.
Connecting to 15.15.183.123...

Couldn't access 15.15.183.123:
```

Here is the result running the same command in cmd.exe in windows container.

```
C:\Windows\Temp>psexec \\\\15.15.183.123 -u Work2019 -p password -s -i 0 -d -e EXPLORER "http://www.google.com"

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Couldn't access 15.15.183.123:
Access is denied.
```

additional Info:

\\15.15.183.123 is a remote machine installed Win10.

work2019 is an administrator on \\15.15.183.123

Run whoami on windows container get following user info:

user manager\containeradministrator

Window container is hosted on a WinServer 2019.

The same command can be execute sucessfully on Docker host WinServer 2019.